# MYSQLi weird characters return null

Tags: php, mysqli

Whenever a field in that particular row contains characters like á à é è ü etc it returns null.

Whenever I execute the query in phpmyadmin it works fine so I am guessing it has something to with mysqli?

```
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT ea_id, nationid, firstname, lastname, commonname, rating FROM players WHERE commonname LIKE '%test%' OR firstname LIKE '%test%' OR lastname LIKE '%test%'");

$record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
print_r($record);
```

Comment: accepting answers show other users that your question has been answered and makes it easy for them to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

should fix your problem.

Also check your page header & database for utf8 encoding.